# initialize localStorage after successful PHP Validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, local-storage

Is there any possible way to initialize localStorage after a successful PHP Validation?

I have 2 separate registration pages/forms and Im using CodeIgniter's form validation library and I want to store registration data in localStorage after validating it in Controller.

What I already did is store input values in localStorage on form submit. But I want to validate the form first before I initialize localStorage.

**Controller**

```
public function register(){
     if($this->input->method == 'post'){
          // form_validation set_rules
          if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
               // initialize localStorage
               // then redirect to registration form 2
          } else {
               // display error message
               // redirect to same page
          }
     }
}
```

**register_view**

```
$("#reg-form1").submit(function(){
    localStorage.firstname          = "<?php echo set_value('reg_first_name'); ?>";
    localStorage.middlename         = "<?php echo set_value('reg_middle_name'); ?>";
    localStorage.lastname           = "<?php echo set_value('reg_last_name'); ?>";
    localStorage.gender             = "<?php echo set_value('reg_gender'); ?>";
    localStorage.birthdate          = "<?php echo set_value('reg_birthdate'); ?>";
    localStorage.address            = "<?php echo set_value('reg_address'); ?>";
    localStorage.email              = "<?php echo set_value('reg_email'); ?>";
    localStorage.mobile_number      = "<?php echo set_value('reg_mobile_number'); ?>"; 
});

<form method="post" id="reg-form1">
     <input type="text" name="reg_first_name">
     // other inputs . . .
     // <submit button
</form>
```

How should I validate the form before initializing localStorage? and what is the best practice on where the localStorage should be placed?

Thank you in advance! :)